# Is there a topological space of cardinality $\kappa$ containing all metric spaces of cardinality $\kappa$?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

It is known that all the countable metrizable spaces embed in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then a natural question is: are there an uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ and a topological space $X$ of cardinality $\kappa$ such that all metrizable spaces of cardinality $\kappa$ embed in $X$?

Because there are exactly $2^\kappa$ pairwise non-homeomorphic metrizable topologies on any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, I can't disprove the existence of such a topological space by a simple size argument. My guess is that it is either independent of ZFC or it is provably false for all cardinals of size at least $2^{\aleph_0}$, using some notion of path-connectivity.

Edit: By the [Kowalski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space#Kowalsky%27s_theorem), any space with a basis of cardinality $\kappa$, so notably any space of cardinality $\kappa$, can be embedded in the product of countably many $\kappa$-Hedgehog spaces. [There is a simple proof of this theorem](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-075-01/S0002-9939-1979-0529240-7/home.html) based mostly on the fact that any metrizable space has a $\sigma$-discrete basis. Hence, we have a positive answer for all cardinals $\kappa$ such that $\kappa^{\aleph_0} = \kappa$. The question is still open for the other cardinals. Thanks to Henno Brandsma for making me aware of this result.

Comment: To clarify, by "embed" you mean "continuously embed," right? (Obviously not every countable metric space *isometrically* embeds into $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: Yes, exactly, I mean a topological embedding.

Comment: +1 BTW, this is a great question. An interesting sub-question: what about the case $\kappa=\omega$ under the assumption of $\mathsf{PFA}$? If memory serves, $\mathsf{PFA}$ implies that any two $\aleph_1$-dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ without endpoints are homeomorphic, so this suggests that we could get a positive answer there.

Comment: @Noah: Your memory appears to be correct; the result is noted at the end of [this MS thesis](https://scholarworks.sjsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4830&context=etd_theses).

Comment: Every metric space of cardinality $\kappa$ (even of density $\kappa$) embeds (even isometrically) into $C([0,1]^\kappa,\Bbb R)$, but this space has too big cardinality.

Comment: @Noah Is there then a hope that ZFC could be consistent with a very strong proposition like all $\aleph_1$ metrizable spaces with open subsets containing $\aleph_1$ points are homeomorphic?

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau No idea, I'm not a set-theoretic topologist. If pressed I'd say it's plausible based on the Baumgartner result, but I really don't have competence in this area. It's a good question.

Comment: Hedgehog space with $\kappa$ spines will do for $\kappa \ge \frak{c}$.

Comment: @Henno You're right! Kowalsky's theorem states that a metrizable space of weight $\kappa$ is embeddable in a product of countably many copies of $\kappa$-Hedgehog spaces, which gives a positive answer for $\kappa \geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ of uncountable cofinality. But then what about cardinals of countable cofinality?

Comment: I was wrong, it is in fact provably false that all $\aleph_1$ metrizable spaces with $\aleph_1$ density are homeomorphic. Such a space $X$ homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be homeomorphic to the disjoint union of $\aleph_1$ many $X$, because we cannot find $\aleph_1$ non-empty disjoint open subsets in $X$. I was also wrong that we have the answer for all cardinals of uncountable cofinality, because $\kappa^{\aleph_0} = \kappa$ is stronger than uncountable cofinality.